# How to efficiently calculate the longest road in catan?

Tags: graph-traversal

[image: Picture of a standard 4 player catan board with all edges filled with blue roads]

In Catan you can calculate the longest road by finding the longest (most roads) path which does not repeat any edges/roads, and does not cross through a vertex controlled by another player.

I started doing an algorithm that:

1. sorts the roads into connected networks (note there is only one of these above)
2. for each road/edge
3. for each of the two verticies
4. recurses if possible with all possible options

This depth first approach is falling over when the board starts to look like this! Any ideas how to do this more efficiently? I was looking at something like Dijkstra's algorithm, but that doesn't work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem